# Regression followed by a t-test?

Tags: regression, t-test

I am new to statistics so basic answers are appreciated. I am a psychology student and am looking at dark triad traits and endorsement for lying. So I have carried out a regression to investigate whether any of the three traits predict endorsement for lying. I then had hoped to see if there was any difference between male and female participants. I ran a t-test but realised that I have only ran it on whether there was a difference between males and females and their endorsement of lying.  This is not good to me as I specifically want to look at whether there was a difference between males and females based on the outcome of the regression - if that makes any sense at all.  My question is - how would I do that?  if it is possible at all.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to cross validated. I am not sure what you mean with "based on the outcome of the regression". I guess you are interested whether there is a significant relationship betwen participants' sex and and endorsement of lying which is not explained by narcissism, psychopathology, and machiavellianism? In that case, I would recommend to add participants' sex (dummy coded) as another independent variable in your analysis.

Comment: thank you - what does dummy coded mean in regards to spss?

Comment: just coding one of them with zero the other one with 1

Answer (score 4):

If you are not familiar with statistics, I think it would be a mistake to jump right into running statistical tests. First, plot your data in various ways, and clarify what question you want statistics to answer. In detail. Once you have an unambiguous question, you can seek help to answer it with stats.

Comment: Shouldn't the question be asked before having the data? But checking your data visually is indeed important to avoid false statistical claims

Comment: I dont have an option of not running a statistical test as the research is for an assignment I am doing.  I decided on - does dark triad traits predict endorsement for lying on a dating profile - this was decided based on a thorough literature review.  My hypothesis is that each trait would predict endorsement for lying.  Because the research says there are differences between men and women I also wanted to see if there would be any significant difference between men and women. I  thought a t test to look at differences between genders but realise that will only tell me about one construct.

Answer (score 3):

> I then had hoped to see if there was **any difference between** male and
>   female participants.

That depends what is being different as implied by your statement above.

If it's "does endorsement differ by sex, after adjusting for trait," then add sex into the regression as another independent variable. Like this:

$$Lying = \beta_0 + \beta_1 traitYes + \beta_2 Male$$

If it's "does the relationship between trait and endorsement differ by sex," then add sex and the interaction between trait and sex into the model. Like this:

$$Lying = \beta_0 + \beta_1 traitYes + \beta_2 Male + \beta_3 traitYes \times Male$$

Suppose Male = 1 for male and Male = 0 for female, for female, the association would be just $\beta_1$, and the association for male would be $\beta_1 + \beta_3$. If $\beta_3$ is different from 0, the association between trait and endorsement differs by sex.

Comment: I appreciate your answers but  I really don't understand what you have just said - i have only just been introduced to statistics and only know the basics of SPSS.  I am specifically trying to see if relationship between trait and endorsement differs by sex.  I hope this clarifies.

Comment: @rach1981 Maybe you should watch Andy Fields videos about regression. They might be a good start for you current level of statistical knowledge [see here](https://www.discoveringstatistics.com/statistics-hell-p/antevorta-predicting-continuous-outcomes/applying-the-linear-model/)

Comment: Thank you.  I will look at that.  Weve only had one short lesson on regression and then expected to do a research paper in 3 weeks including analysing data etc.